# Cocos2d doesn't use the entire screen of iphone 5

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, screen

I have a problem with my application ios. It is a universal application of cocos2d 6.0. It works on ipad, iphone 3GS, 4, 4S. Iphone 5 on I can start the application but cocos2d does not use the entire screen. Like iPhone 4. Do you have any idea??

Thank's

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you added to your project the Default-568h@2x.png launch image? This will make your app use the full iPhone 5 screen.

If you do not include that launch image, then your app will work in boxed mode (i.e., centered on screen with black bands above and below to fill the entire area).

*Note : this is due to the devices different screen resolutions :*

iPhone 4 : 960x640 px.
iPhone 5 : 1136x640 px.

Comment: Now the problem is that it uses iphone 4 view ... the buttons are not in good locations etc. ... I want to use the iphone 5 view. In the info.plist I create a new nib file base name Main: MainWindows-iPhone5. But it uses the Main nib file base name (iPhone): MainWindow-iphone. And I can't create two Main nib file base name (iphone) ...

Comment: there is no provision in the SDK to manage the nib based on file extension/device (in this respect, iPhone5 does not work as an iPad). You will have to check the screen height and load the proper nib. Better yet, you might try to play with the autoresize options of your UI elements, so that they adapt to the larger screen area, but it is not always easy.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to screen size differences between iphone5 and iphone 3G, 4, 4s.

iPhone 4 :960 x 640 px

iPhone 5 1136 x 640 px

You should use Default-568h@2x.png image name for your launch image. On starting iphone 5 will load this image which will cover whole screen, While for other images in your game(If you have different images for iPhone5) use following code in your AppDelegate.m

```
[CCFileUtils setiPhoneFourInchDisplaySuffix:@"your suffix"];
```

And place images in project according to your suffix.